# How to solve this Jquery problem

Tags: jquery, css

I have page with `jQuery` [Click here to see](http://www.cpantry.com/jquery/)
code for this site is

```
<script type=""  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js" ></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var delay = 4000; // you can change it
      var count = 5; // How much items to animate
      var showing = 3; //How much items to show at a time
      var i = 0;
      function move(i) {
        return function() {
          $('#feed'+i).remove().css('display', 'none').prependTo('#feeds');
        }
      }
      function shift() {
        var toShow = (i + showing) % count;
        $('#feed'+toShow).slideDown(1000, move(i));
        $('#feed'+i).slideUp(1000, move(i));
        i = (i + 1) % count;
        setTimeout('shift()', delay);
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout('shift()', delay);
      });
  </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        
            <div class="slider">Wait for just 4 seconds...!
            <div class="sliding"><div id="feeds">
<div class="item" id="feed0"  style="display: none;"><img alt="image"  src="http://www.flashdaweb.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/website_development_program.jpg" width="125" height="100"></div><div class="info">hello this is me</div></div>
<div class="item2" id="feed1" style="display: none;"><div class="thumbnail1"><img alt="image"  src="http://www.esellswebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/designing-a-fast-loading-website.jpg" width="125" height="100"></div><div class="info1">hello </div></div>
</div></div>
```

Now come towards the problems. I'm new to `jQuery` thats why my question might be stupid.

 
**1:** When the page load why it takes so much time to start sliding.
**2:**After sliding is completed it starts in reverse order i.e its slide up in the end i comment

```
$('#feed'+i).slideUp(1000, move(i));
```

this line but then the slide will stop when it completed. so is there a way to continously start the slide in slidedown direction.

Comment: @source code: try reducing the `delay` variable value to say 2000 set `delay=2000`

Comment: @S.M.09: delaya time is the time between slides changes not the starting delay time.

Comment: then you should not set Interval for shift in ready function instead call it without setInterval like
`shift();` instead `setTimeout('shift()', delay);`

Comment: Instead of adding this from a url `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js` add the `jquery-1.5.js` in the same folder that of the page and change the script included to `<script type=""  src="jquery-1.5.js" ></script>`....here download it from here [JQuery 1.5](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js)..I think because the JS is located at some other place it taking time to load at at the first place there after its in the browser so it would work fine...

Comment: @Naren: ok thats great but my actual problem is why the slide reverse after completion. i want it to be continued in same direction.

Comment: try `i = (i + 1) % showing;`  instead `i = (i + 1) % count;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the number of items to 5:

```
var count = 5;
```

set it to 2, because there are only 2 items to animate.

You can also set it dynamic on $(document).ready:

```
count=$('#feeds div[id^="feed"]').length;
```

Comment: Actually i want to extract the data dynamically from mysql table. so could you please explain your last line of code i tried this but couldn't get it.

Comment: The last line of code is a jQuery selector. It looks inside an element with the `id` of `feeds`, to *find* those `div`s with an `id` that begins-with the string 'feed'. This returns a collection of jQuery objects. The `length` method simply returns the number of elements that were found by the selector. Reference: [attribute-starts-with (`^=`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/).